# Path independent Derby network database service

Tags: java, database, jdbc, server, derby

I have a server end application which creates a database using this URL:

```
jdbc:derby:abssposdb;create=true
```

This creates the derby database in the project folder. 
And i am starting a network server for this database using the following code

```
String[] args = {"start", "-h", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "4321"};
    try {
        org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(args);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Now, in order to connect to this database the URL that i have to use is

```
jdbc:derby://192.168.1.12:4321/C:\Users\mtahm\Documents\NetBeansProjects\derbyEmbeded\abssposdb
```

As you can see the whole path has to be specified. This is a problem because for me because I need this derby server to be accessible using the URL below so that the whole application will be dynamic

```
jdbc:derby://192.168.1.12:4321/abssposdb
```

I am guessing some sort of background service or something similar will be required but I have no clue how to do this. Is there a technique for doing this? My whole project is in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Derby Network Server locates databases named with relative path names by interpreting those relative path names against derby.system.home, the Derby Network Server's "home" directory.

For more information about derby.system.home, see: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefproper32066.html

You can control the interpretation of the database name portion of the Connection URL by controlling the value of derby.system.home for your Derby Network Server. There's a lot more information here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/devguide/cdevdvlp34964.html#cdevdvlp34964

So: your database can be located anywhere; your Derby Network Server can run on any machine, and can service requests for any databases on that machine. But, to tie those things together, you need to establish some organization and policy for where you want to store your databases, and by using conventions like derby.system.home, you can ensure that your databases aren't scattered all over the place, but are collected in a single location for you to find when you need to back them up, upgrade them, etc.

Comment: It worked. Setting the derby home using system wide property has allowed the use of proper short URL. Great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the db with "jdbc:derby:abssposdb;create=true" as it is designed to create embedded db. The server doesn't know about the embedded DB you are creating, it is why you need to specify whole path to this db. 
**All you need to do to create DB accessible by a simple name is to connect to this server (after you start it by NetworkServerControl.main()) with a special connection URL, like this:**

```
jdbc:derby://192.168.1.12:4321/abssposdb;create=true
```

Notice the **"create=true"** at the end of this URL, this will create database accessible on url `jdbc:derby://192.168.1.12:4321/abssposdb` if it doesn't already exist, or just connect to it if exist.

Comment: At first i was creating the embedded database and then starting the server, which obviously wasn't working the way i wanted. So according to your solution I changed my code so that the server is started first and then the database connection and or creation is done. Problem is when the server is started execution is paused, further lines are not executed. Do i have to execute the connection URL in a separate thread? Please keep in mind i am starting the server and creating the database within the same program. The client end programs will only connect to this server program.